# Python, Pandas, select row with multindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using python 3.6.2 and pandas latest.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
                                                                    start_time
station_id                           date       daypart                          
237a55b1-ca3a-35e8-b2d0-5a839cf9311e 2017-10-01 AMD        2017-10-01 10:00:00   
                                                Evening    2017-10-01 23:00:00   
                                                Midday     2017-10-01 14:00:00   
                                                Overnight  2017-10-01 04:00:00   
                                                PMD        2017-10-01 19:00:00
```

I would like to select the row with index `['237a55b1-ca3a-35e8-b2d0-5a839cf9311e', '2017-10-01', 'AMD']` to return `237a55b1-ca3a-35e8-b2d0-5a839cf9311e 2017-10-01 AMD        2017-10-01 10:00:00`

is this kind of lookup possible? I have been reading the documentation for  `.loc` and `.iloc` but not sure if thats the right path...

And help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
df.loc[(index_1, index_2, index_3)]
```

Comment: Random internet stranger you are my hero! `df.loc[('237a55b1-ca3a-35e8-b2d0-5a839cf9311e', '2017-10-01', 'AMD')]` worked like a charm.

Comment: works same with multicolumns:
df[(col_index_1, col_index_2)]